# syntax error in insert into statement. c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Syntax error in insert into statement happens while I try to update my MS Access database.

- Database name = student
- Table name = student table

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO student table([Name],[Class])" + "values('" + textBox1 + "','" + textBox2 + "')";
        connection.Close();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");           
}
```

Comment: You need to call the text property of the textbox to get the string value, for example, textBox1.Text.

Comment: Is the name of the table `Student Table` or `Student`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1st you need to use `textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text` instead of
  `textBox1` and `textBox2` respectively.
- 2nd don't close the connection before executing the command.
- 3rd use parameters.

So to sum up:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [student table] ([Name],[Class]) values(@par1,@par2)";
command.Paramaters.Add("@par1",textBox1.Text);  
command.Paramaters.Add("@par2",textBox2.Text);    
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

If your table name is more than one word, you need to use it with square brackets like `[student table]`

But much more important, you should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [student table]([Name],[Class]) 
                                VALUES(?, ?)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox2);

        connection.Open();
        int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        if(count > 0)
           MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");  
    }        
}
```

By the way, I suspect if these `textBox1` and `textBox2` are `TextBox` not a variable, you need to use them with their `.Text` properties.

Comment: would you please provide me full code  where i can add name and address into ms access database using SAVE botton?